# Parsing string data response

Tags: json, query-string, string-parsing

I am stuck in parsing a data response receiving from some third party vendor.
response is something like:-

```
data: ()(responseCode='A01', responseMessage='Approved', accountNumber='qwerty');
```

I have tried several ways of parsing/stringify but it does not provide me a JSON response. I tried weird combinations of Querystring functions as well but that did not help.
I am badly stuck in this.

Answer (score 0):

I will post a workaround it might not be efficient but will give you the result.

```js
var data = "data: ()(responseCode='A01', responseMessage='Approved', accountNumber='qwerty');";
var temp = data.substring(8,);
temp = temp.replace("(","{");
temp = temp.replace(")","}");
temp = temp.replace(/=/g,":");
temp = temp.replace(";","");
temp = eval('(' + temp + ')');
var Result = JSON.stringify(temp)
```

Result : {"responseCode":"A01","responseMessage":"Approved","accountNumber":"qwerty"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to convert it to a valid JSON structure.

```js
let data = `data: ()(responseCode='A01', responseMessage='Approved', accountNumber='qwerty');`;

let modified = data
.replace(/\s/g,'')
.replace("data:()(",'{\'')
.replace(");",'}')
.replace(/=/g,"':")
.replace(/,/g,",'")
.replace(/'/g,'"')

let json = JSON.parse(modified);
console.log(json)
```